# Using Bundler in deployment

Tags: ruby, deployment, rubygems, bundler, unicorn

Pretty fundamental question but I'm trying to understand how best to use Bundler in a deployment situation.

I'm working on a Sinatra application that has about 20 dependent gems. During development, I'm using RVM with a custom gemset for the application, and I run `bundle install` to update the gemset in accordance with the gemfile.

When it comes to deployment (manually for now, so I can understand how it all works before using a tool like capistrano), I need to do `bundle install --development` right? This downloads the gems and places them in `vendor/bundle`.

My question is what else do I need to do? I'm using Unicorn on the server - do I just `bundle exec unicorn ...` and everything just works? (i.e. bundler finds the vendor directory and uses the gems from there?)

Should unicorn be a vendored gem in the application or a separate 'system' gem on the server that all applications share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need --deployment key, not --development: http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-install.1.html#DEPLOYMENT-MODE

On first run bundler creates config in .bundle directory. You can check it by running `bundle config` or just `cat .bundle/config` in project's directory. So **bundle exec unicorn** is enough since bundler knows where gems are installed. On development machine you can also install gems to arbitrary directory using --path key. For more details see manpage for bundle install (link above or `bundle help install`).

Comment: Oops, my bad, I actually meant to type deployment. Thanks for confirming that `bundle exec` does what I expected it to and locates the local project gems.